# How to execute function and update current state in background even app closed via Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, dispatch

I would like to create some function which will be activated in some period even app completely terminated. If I should give an example like timer in clock app (default app by apple). It will continue count down even app completely terminated.

I try code in the below but it trigger only one time. I put code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(10)
```

also I added this function too with activate background capabilities from settings

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        print("Background")
        sharedDefault.set(true, forKey:"Status")
        sharedDefault.synchronize()
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Basically I want to change user status true every day. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: It looks likes duplicate but that answer is not quite enough i think. I've done research and found this solution in my question but it didn't worked. I need a direction. That answer generally explain the solution of problem

Comment: You aren't calling the completion handler, so iOS won't perform the background fetch again. There is no need to call `synchronize`

Comment: application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(10) should call after 10 second that why i added in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @KemalEkren it seems like you have a misunderstanding about how background fetch works. You as a developer have no control over when a background fetch is performed. `application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` only sets a _minimum_ interval, meaning that the system will not call a background fetch for your app any sooner than the interval you set from after the previous fetch, but it doesn't guarantee that a fetch will be executed at that time. The system decides when to perform a background fetch and whether to perform one at all or not.

Comment: then maybe i should Instead of keep count down in the background, I can record the start time and store in the db. When open or resume the app, take the time and calculate the duration according to this calculation execute function ?

Comment: It certainly won't call you every 10 seconds. You can set `backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` but the interval will still depend on the value you pass back to the completion handler and whether you actually perform a background fetch.

Comment: yes you are right when i try to Debug-> Simulate Background Fetch it triggered